# What does the Facebook iPhone app use to display pages in an app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

When you tap a link on the Facebook app it links to an in app browser, probably rendering via safari. I'm just wondering how do i use this in my app?

Answer (score 3):

The Facebook for iPhone app uses a self written framework named [three20](http://three20.info/). The [TTWebController](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_web_controller.php) provides a reduced in app browser. It's open source and pretty easy to use. Just give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `UIWebView` -- the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) contains many examples.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need more than a UIWebView? That will render the page, and allows links on the page to be followed. You can also tell the UIWebView to go back and forward, and reload. You can use that to add those functions yourself.

Ref: [UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)